# Move cursor at the end of the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my little jquery plugin that replaces each english symbol with other symbols while typing. Everything works fine here except when I type a long word, longer than the input itself, the cursor goes outside the input the the last part of the word isn't visible. Just visit the link bellow and type something (without the space) and you'll get what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/beLMf/

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: The cursor *is* at the end. What you mean is keeping the tip of the text visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems one is that you add the text to then end of the line all the time that is if it matches the characters you are looking for. You should instead do the insert at the caret(cursor) position:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
insertAtCaret: function(myValue){
  return this.each(function(i) {
    if (document.selection) {
      //For browsers like Internet Explorer
      this.focus();
      sel = document.selection.createRange();
      sel.text = myValue;
      this.focus();
    }
    else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
      //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
      var startPos = this.selectionStart;
      var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
      var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+myValue+this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
      this.focus();
      this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
      this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
      this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    } else {
      this.value += myValue;
      this.focus();
    }
  })
}
});
```

Then change your line:

```
$this.val( $this.val() + String.fromCharCode( i + 4304 ) );
```

to

```
$this.insertAtCaret(String.fromCharCode( i + 4304 ));
$("#switcher").focus();
$(this).focus();
```

that will solve your issue and also solve the problem of editing any part of the string.

update:
To make the cursor position update we have to switch focus away and then back to the element

I made the changes to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beLMf/6/) there is also a function to capture cursor position  that I was thinking of using to solve your problem there. It just outputs to console.log and you can delete that.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, this doesn't appear to solve the issue.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I've updated the fiddle with the working code. http://jsfiddle.net/beLMf/6/

Comment: You are right :)) anyway that's a great answer, Thanks for help!